# javascript form numbers

Tags: javascript, forms, numbers

My first day of Javascript and I am incredibly confused. I am passing numbers returned from a form to a function, but the result is not consistent with what it should be. My testing leaves a lot to be desired, but hopefully the following makes sense.

The function `g` calculates the sum of the sequence.

```
 <form name="gaussform">
    <input name="min" 
           type="number"
           min="1"
           value="1">
    <input name="max" 
           type="number"
           min="2"
           value="10">
    <input name="step" 
           type="number"
           min="1"
           value="1">
    <input onclick="alert_g()"
           type="submit"
           value="calculate">
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function g(min,max,step) {
    var actualmax = max - ((max - min) % step)
    return (min + actualmax) * ((1 + ((actualmax - min) / step)) / 2)
    }

    function alert_g() {
    var frm = document.forms["gaussform"]
    var min = frm["min"].value
    var max = frm["max"].value
    var step = frm["step"].value
    if (min == 1) {
    alert("min is 1")}
    if (max == 10) {
    alert("max is 10")}
    if (step == 1) {
    alert("step is 1")}
    alert(g(min,max,step))
    // below returns the desired result
    alert(g(1,10,1))}
  </script>
```

the if statements are only so I can understand what is going on!

So if the user enter 1,10,1 (the default values) the result should be 55.

`alert(g(1,10,1))` -> 55

`alert(g(min,max,step)` -> 550

`alert(g(1,100,2))` -> 2500

`alert(g(min,max,step)` -> 4975 (obviously min,max,step == 1,100,2)

the function `g` is correct, but I do not understand what is happening to the values that are being passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression...

```
min + actualmax
```

...is the problem.

You probably want to make that...

```
+min + +actualmax
```

...or use `parseFloat()`, `parseInt()` or whatever suits your requirements to turn those strings into an actual `Number`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EVgGn/).

JavaScript's `+` operator is overloaded for arithmetic addition and string concatenation. Because user input is *always* a string, you're doing string concatenation.

Comment: +1 for explaining. I chose the parseInt so to keep the function `g` clean.

Answer (score 2):

The values you use in your function are strings (every value returned by a form will be a string). You need to convert them to number to get the good result. This can be done with `parseFloat` function.

```
parseFloat('5') // return 5
```

`parseInt` can also be used if you want an Integer (no floating point number e.g.: `1.3`), but be sure to set the radix parameter in order to always get consistent results.

```
parseInt('5', 10) // return 5
```

This can be confusing because Javascript use the `+` symbol for addition and concatenations of strings (which is `.` sign in PHP for example). As so, it's hard for the javascript engine to know how a value is expected to be converted.

By the way, you can always use `typeof` operator to checkout the type of a variable. For example:

```
typeof '5' // ouput: String
typeof 5   // output: Number
```

Comment: you must have written this just as I was having my revelation!

Answer (score 0):

`alert(g(parseInt(min),parseInt(max),parseInt(step)))` has solved it!

But apparently this is bad form. See comments...

`alert(g(parseInt(min,10),parseInt(max,10),parseInt(step,10)))` perhaps?

Comment: Always use the 2-argument form of `parseInt`.

Comment: @melpomene Always? That's a dangerous term in software development. What about `var paddingTop = parseInt(elem.style.paddingTop);`?

Comment: @melpomene Would you say I need to provide the radix there?

Comment: You always need to provide the radix. Don't let the interpreter guess what you meant to do, tell it what you want to do.

Comment: @melpomene So `parseInt("16")` isn't perfectly safe?

Comment: @alex No, but that doesn't require `parseInt` in the first place: Just write `16`.

Comment: @rlemon It doesn't guess, it looks to see if the string looks like octal (`0n`) or hexadecimal (`0xn`), both of which are deterministic. I actually couldn't reproduce the octal one anymore, seems it was *fixed* in Chrome.

Comment: @alex [That is exactly the problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix).

Comment: @melpomene My point was, if you know the string never has a leading zero, then adding the base is safety against a non-issue. I see your point though, it's easier to always add it rather than consider it on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: To steal a quote from MDN to further back my point: "While this parameter is optional, always specify it to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified.". This is being stated because you cannot always guarantee all implementations will provide the same defaults.